# Posts tagged "qtp" don't have correct code highlighting

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Posts tagged [qtp](/questions/tagged/qtp) should have their code highlighted according to VBScript rules since QTP scripts are based on VBScript.

Comment: Fair enough, but I would tag this "feature-request" not "bug". This is a missing feature, not a not-working one

Comment: @Pekka, point, I changed it. The reason I marked it as bug is that I requested this in the original syntax highlighting thread and was ignored. IMO the process of associating tags with languages is fatally flawed.